# Handling inputStream.open() error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tcp

I'm trying to build an iOS app that reads JSON data from a local server via a TCP socket.  Everything works OK if the server is available when the app loads, but it throws errors to the console when I try to open the input stream if the server is not available.  I am trying to find a way to catch this error and handle it.  I would like the app to just keep trying to connect until the server is available.  But since the method doesnt return any value or throw an error I am not show how to determine when this situation has occurred.

(BTW the error I receive is "Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]"

I'd be grateful for any advice !  Thanks

My code :

```
var inputStream: InputStream!
    
func setupNetworkCommunication() {
        
var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                           K.serverIPAddress as CFString,
                                           K.serverPort,
                                           &readStream,
                                           &writeStream)
        
inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
inputStream.delegate = self
inputStream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .common)
inputStream.open()
```

Comment: You may want to check the stream's error with property `streamError` after calling `open()`. Alternatively, check global variable `errno` from Darwin.C.

Answer (score 0):

the error seems like in your *readStream!.takeRetainedValue()* line, can u add exception breakpoint to your project for handle the crash? and than I will try to help you in this post :)

Follow these steps:

- Open XCode breakpoint menu from pannel
- Add exception breakpoint to
  your project
- Check it, and run the project.

Check it out please for how to add breakpoint:

[image: Open xcode breakpoint menu]

[image]

[image]

Xcode will automatically stop you while crashing. Please notify me the results.
Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for advice.  I tried this but the break point was never called.  I realise that actually xcode is not crashing just giving me an error that it cant connect.  Stepping through line by line - it is apparent that it is on inputStream.open() that the error message occurs.  However it still leaves me with the problem trying to capture this - so that I can keep trying to open the input stream periodically.  The problem I have is that inputStream.open() does not return anything and does not throw any error

Comment: I will update post to reflect that it is not actually crashing - but I still want to try and capture the error.  Thanks !